# reledmac: narrower margin for footnotes, lining up with body + sidenotes

Tags: margins, footnotes, sidenotes, reledmac

In a document with sidenotes and footnotes using reledmac, is there a way to expand footnotes into the margin so that the then-narrower footnote margin is the same as the part of the margin on the outside of sidenotes? [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188189/footnote-taking-width-of-both-body-and-margin-note) is an illustration and a solution for footnotes outside of reledmac. I tried adapting that solution with `\Xbhooknote` and `\Xbhookgroup` (commented out below), which does not have the desired effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=2.2in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\ledrsnotewidth = 1.5in
\rightnoteupfalse
%\Xbhooknote{\hsize\columnwidth\advance\hsize\marginparsep\advance\hsize\marginparwidth}
%\Xbhookgroup{\hsize\columnwidth\advance\hsize\marginparsep\advance\hsize\marginparwidth}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{Lorem}{
    \Afootnote{\lipsum*[1]}
    \Bfootnote{\lipsum*[1-2]}}
\ledsidenote{A side note long enough to wrap to the next line.}
\lipsum*[2-3]
\ledsidenote{Another side note.}
```

Comment: the main problem is that you use paragraphed and column footnote, which complexify data. I have found a way for paragraphed, not for colum. I look on it.

Comment: I have found for the column. But it's require some adaptation on reledmac. I will try to do it tonight.

Comment: issue opened https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/461

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The v2.7.0 of reledmac, send on CTAN on 2015/11/29, provides two new hook,`\Xhsize[<s>]{<l>}` and `\hsizeX[<s>]{<l>}` to set the width for respectivly critical and familiar footnote.

`<l>` is a dimen expression, parsable with `\dimexpr`.

Cf this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\setmainlanguage{latin}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[noend,noeledsec,noledgroup,series={A,B,C,D}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\Xarrangement[C]{threecol}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{twocol}
\arrangementX[C]{threecol}
\Xhsize{\columnwidth+\marginparsep+\ledrsnotewidth}
\hsizeX{\columnwidth+\marginparsep+\ledrsnotewidth}
\rightnoteupfalse

\AtBeginDocument{%
 \maxhnotesX{0.8\textheight}
 \Xmaxhnotes{0.8\textheight}
}
\Xcolalign{\justifying}
\colalignX{\justifying}
\begin{document}

\begin{english}
\title{Setting footnotes width}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This example use  \verb+maxhnotesX+ and \verb+Xmaxhnotes+ to set the width of familiar and critical footnotes. The width is set to \verb+\columnwidth+\marginparsep+\ledrsnotewidth+, that means footnotes go from the left of the text to the right of the sidenotes.
\end{abstract}
\end{english}
\newpage
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{Lorem}{
    \Afootnote{A\lipsum*[1]}
    \Bfootnote{B\lipsum*[2]}
    \Cfootnote{C\lipsum*[3]}
    \Dfootnote{D\lipsum*[4]}
    }
Dolor
\ledsidenote{A long side note.}
\lipsum*[1]
\pend
\newpage
\pstart
\lipsum*[2]\ledsidenote{A long side note.}\footnoteA{A\lipsum*[5]}\footnoteB{B\lipsum*[6]}\footnoteC{C\lipsum*[7]}\footnoteD{D\lipsum*[8]}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```