# Footnote below left margin

Tags: footnotes, margins

I have a relatively wide left margin at my document since there are several annotations there. I want now that any footnote starts below this margin and not with indent under the main text. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, give us a MWE so that we can help you.

Comment: Related, unanswered question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314641/footnote-margins

Comment: Maybe this?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279491/reledmac-narrower-margin-for-footnotes-lining-up-with-body-sidenotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I patched `\@footnotetext` to add a `\leftskip`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\@parboxrestore}{\@parboxrestore\leftskip-1in}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
a\footnote{\lipsum*[3]}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To additionally extend the footnote rule leftward, I patch `\footnoterule`, as well:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\@parboxrestore}{\@parboxrestore\leftskip-1in}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\footnoterule}{\hrule}{\llap{\smash{\rule[-.4pt]{1in}{.4pt}}}\hrule}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
a\footnote{\lipsum*[3]}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to adapt this to inner and outer margins rather than right and left margins?

Comment: @BryanM-H It would take a bit of work.  Were you to try it, I would suggest turning my `\leftskip`s into `\rightskip`s to see if it gives what you want for the alternate page.  Then the difficulty would be in figuring out whether you were on an even or odd page number, and choosing to proper sense of the skip, left or right.

Comment: I had gotten stuck drawing the footnoterule to the right; I don't understand what all the commands do:

     \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
     \usepackage{lipsum}
     \usepackage{xpatch}
     \makeatletter
     \xpatchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\@parboxrestore}{\@parboxrestore\rightskip-1in}{}{}
     \xpatchcmd{\footnoterule}{\hrule}{\hspace{5.5in} \llap{\smash{\rule[.4pt]{1in}{.4pt}}}\hrule}{}{}
     \makeatother
     \begin{document}
     a\footnote{\lipsum*[3]}
     \lipsum[1-5]
     \end{document}
This left me with a rule on both right and left and I put it aside.

Comment: @BryanM-H Since the footnote rule is, as a rule, flush left, what exactly are you hoping to achieve for the look of a right-extending rule?  Once you can formulate this more precisely, if I cannot help, consider asking it as a new question.

Comment: Sorry, @StevenB.Segletes; I wasn't thinking. After getting the text to the side I wanted, I started trying to`adjust' the footnote rule to the other side too... without pausing to realize it shouldn't be moved at all.