# Even-page footnotes extend into inner margin using reledmac three-column footnotes

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

I am using the method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279713/235141) (updated since `\hsizeX` is deprecated and replaced by `\widthX`) to extend my footnotes into the margin.  I had hoped this would be the outer margin, and it is on odd-numbered pages.  However on even-numbered pages, it extends to the inner margin.  The example at the link above is in the `article` class, but I am using `book`, so the margins are different.  I tried to utilize `\fancyfootoffset` from `fancyhdr` to fix this, but it did nothing.  I am unsure whether I am using it incorrectly or if it fails because I am using `reledmac`'s footnotes and not the default.  Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\arrangementX[A]{threecol}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\widthX{\columnwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}

\newlength{\myOffset}{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfootoffset[LE]{\myOffset}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nulla aliquet enim tortor\footnote{This is a footnote.} at auctor urna nunc. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet. Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis. Vel elit scelerisque\footnote{This is another footnote.} mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros.

    Dolor sit amet\footnote{Here we find another footnote.} consectetur adipiscing elit. Libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus.

    Lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Massa\footnote{There are more footnotes everywhere.} id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Purus non enim praesent elementum. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Turpis\footnote{This is another example footnote.} in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam.

    Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Eget mi proin sed libero enim. Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet. Ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Egestas diam in arcu cursus. Et malesuada\footnote{This footnote appears on second page.} fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum.

    Mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim. Tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ut placerat orci nulla\footnote{This footnote is necessary.} pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut. Sed id semper risus in hendrerit. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis\footnote{This footnote has text extending off the page past the inner margin, because the text extends the wrong way.}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Using `fancyhdr` won't help much here, because the footnotes are not in the footer of the page. The most straightforward way I can currently think of to achieve this is to wrap the whole footnote block in an `minipage` (or some other box) and shift it to the left on even pages. I used the package `etoolbox` to check whether the current page is even or odd and to patch the relevant commands that print the footnote block onto the page.

The first approach is to wrap the whole footnote block including the footnoterule and shift everything to the left on even pages. However, wrapping the footnotes like this seems to have some impact on vertical spacing. Wrapping the footnotes in a `minipage` on both pages makes the spacing the same, but since vertical spacing is affected, this approach will leave ugly spaces across the page.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\arrangementX[A]{threecol}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\widthX{\columnwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}

\newlength{\footnoteoffset}
\setlength{\footnoteoffset}{\dimexpr(-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth)}

\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\append@notesX}{\print@notesX{#1}}{\ifnumodd{\thepage}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\print@notesX{#1}\end{minipage}}{\noindent\hspace*{\footnoteoffset}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\print@notesX{#1}\end{minipage}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nulla aliquet enim tortor\footnote{This is a footnote.} at auctor urna nunc. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet. Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis. Vel elit scelerisque\footnote{This is another footnote.} mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros.

    Dolor sit amet\footnote{Here we find another footnote.} consectetur adipiscing elit. Libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus.

    Lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Massa\footnote{There are more footnotes everywhere.} id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Purus non enim praesent elementum. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Turpis\footnote{This is another example footnote.} in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam.

    Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Eget mi proin sed libero enim. Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet. Ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Egestas diam in arcu cursus. Et malesuada\footnote{This footnote appears on second page.} fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum.

    Mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim. Tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ut placerat orci nulla\footnote{This footnote is necessary.} pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut. Sed id semper risus in hendrerit. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis\footnote{This footnote has text extending off the page past the inner margin, because the text extends the wrong way.}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The red overlay depicts the original position of the footnotes and body text, showing the vertical spacing problem.

---

Better than that, but sill not optimal is another approach that does not shift the whole block including the footnote rule, but the block containing the footnotes and the one containing the rule separately. This way, the problem with vertical spacing seems to be solved. Instead a small horizontal space is added in front of the footnote block.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\arrangementX[A]{threecol}
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\widthX{\columnwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}

\newlength{\footnoteoffset}
\setlength{\footnoteoffset}{\dimexpr(-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth)}

\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\print@footnoteXrule}{\moveleft-\leftskip}{\ifnumodd{\thepage}{\moveleft-\leftskip}{\moveleft-\footnoteoffset}}{}{}

\patchcmd{\print@footnoteruleX}{\moveleft-\leftskip}{\ifnumodd{\thepage}{\moveleft-\leftskip}{\noindent\hspace*{\footnoteoffset}\moveleft-\leftskip}}{}{}

\patchcmd{\print@notesX}{\csuse{footgroup#1}{#1}}{\ifnumodd{\thepage}{\noindent\hspace*{0pt}\csuse{footgroup#1}{#1}}{\noindent\hspace*{\footnoteoffset}\csuse{footgroup#1}{#1}}\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nulla aliquet enim tortor\footnote{This is a footnote.} at auctor urna nunc. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet. Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis. Vel elit scelerisque\footnote{This is another footnote.} mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros.

    Dolor sit amet\footnote{Here we find another footnote.} consectetur adipiscing elit. Libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Pharetra et ultrices neque ornare aenean. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus.

    Lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Massa\footnote{There are more footnotes everywhere.} id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Purus non enim praesent elementum. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Turpis\footnote{This is another example footnote.} in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam.

    Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Eget mi proin sed libero enim. Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet. Ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Egestas diam in arcu cursus. Et malesuada\footnote{This footnote appears on second page.} fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum.

    Mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim. Tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ut placerat orci nulla\footnote{This footnote is necessary.} pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut. Sed id semper risus in hendrerit. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis\footnote{This footnote has text extending off the page past the inner margin, because the text extends the wrong way.}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what causes it, but when I insert this code into my full document, I get an extra line between all paragraphs.  I have tried commenting out other parts of the preamble to see if I can find which is interacting to cause this, but I cannot find it.  Unfortunately that removes the benefit gained from extending the footnotes, because it still takes up extra space.  Still you answered the question I asked with the MWE provided.

Comment: I observed that the box with the footnotes is shifted a bit downwards when I use my apporoach. I would assume that this happens rather late in the compilation process and LaTeX then tries to adjust the already calculated text blocks by inserting the spaces you detected. I tried a lot of different ways to achieve this without hacking too much into the package code, but I could not find another solution. You could ask the creator of the package about a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might be something like that.  Because I have many more footnotes in my actual document, the footnotes actually end up running past the page numbers at the beginning of each chapter.  I was looking at the package code for a way to hack it, and it is just WAY beyond my level.

Comment: My original approach was to actually find the box that wraps all the footnotes. But I did not find it. If there was one single box that contains everything, you could just shift it to the left (only on even pages of course). Hence, in the end, I wrapped everything into a new box, but this finally conflicted with vertical alignment. =(

Comment: @pokyCoder I just tried again and came up with another solution that should not contain the vertical spacing problem. However, it adds some horizontal space in front of the footnote block.

Comment: This is beautiful.  I resolved the horizontal space by changing `\hspace*{0pt}` to `\hspace*{-5pt}` on odd pages and `\hspace*{\footnoteoffset}` to `\hspace*{\dimexpr(\footnoteoffset-5pt)}` on even pages.  Works like gangbusters.  The only problem left is migrating those pesky `marginpar`s up when they run into the footnotes...

Comment: notes that reledmac already requires etoolbox :)